# Ctrl-c causes cygwin to crash on ghci

Tags: haskell, cygwin

I am using cygwin for Haskell development. When I try to exit from a session with Ctrl-C the console freezes and subsequently crashes.

Any idea of how I could exit `ghci` without a crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start `ghci` on Windows, it displays this message:

```
$ ghci
WARNING: GHCi invoked via 'ghci.exe' in *nix-like shells (cygwin-bash, in particular)
         doesn't handle Ctrl-C well; use the 'ghcii.sh' shell wrapper instead
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
```

Instead of running `ghci`, run `ghcii.sh`.